# Getting Monday 00:00 and Sunday 23:59 by a specific date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a date time value, for example: `'2014-10-09 11:09'`.

I'd like to get two date time values:

- the date of monday on that week with time 00:00:00 (`2014-10-06
  00:00:00`)
- the date of sunday on that week with time 23:59:59
  (`2014-10-12 23:59:59`)

In short words: I have given a date time value for which I need to determine the starting and ending second of that week.

I've came up with this so far:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @time DATETIME2(0) = '2014-10-09 11:09';

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @time), @time))),
    DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @time), @time))))
```

This does the job but its seems very complex and I need an eaiser solution because of readability. This also runs very fast with hundreds of thousands of rows which is a requirement.

Do you know any eaiser solution? I prefer not using conversion to cut the time part from `@time`.

System: SQL Server 2012

Comment: If you're trying to define a range, I'd seriously recommend that you use the *exclusive* endpoint of `2014-10-13T00:00:00` and use `<` rather than `<=` for comparison purposes. It's both easier to calculate and doesn't exclude anything that happens *during* the final second of the Sunday (e.g. something with a timestamp of `2014-10-12T23:59:59.997`)

Comment: Thanks. It's a good advice that I'll take into account :)

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @TIME DATETIME2(0) = '2014-10-09 11:09';

SELECT DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, @TIME), 0) -- FIRST DAY OF WEEK
SELECT DATEADD(SS, 86399, DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK, 0, @TIME), 0) + 6) -- LAST DAY OF WEEK
```

Comment: On Sundays this will start reporting the following week.

Answer (score 2):

These expressions will always generate the start and end dates for a range, if you're happy to switch to my suggested alternative where the end date is an exclusive date:

```
select
  DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/7,'19000101') as Start,
  DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/7,'19000108') as Finish
```

Where `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can be replaced in both places if you're wanting to find the appropriate Monday's for some date and time that isn't the current one.

This works by working out the number of days that have happened since a "known good Monday" (in this case, 1st January 1900 was a Monday). We then divide that number of days by 7 (ignoring the remainder, as happens automatically in SQL Server with integer division) and add that number of weeks back onto the same "known good Monday" - the end result being that we've effectively found the most recent Monday in the past.

We then do exactly the same trick again except this time when we come to add a number of weeks back on, we actually add it to the Monday that happened a week later than our "known good Monday" - with the net effect that we actually obtain the next Monday in the future.